# Cartesian Equation to Parametric Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a Cartesian equation, $2x - 3y = 5$, and the parametric equation for it is given as $$(x,y) = (4,1) + t(3,2)$$

I have tried making $2x = 5+3t$, $y=t$ etc, but can't figure out how they get this parametric equation?

Please help?

Comment: Replace $x=4+3t$ and solve for $y$. Also, you can substitute $y=1+2t$ and solve for $x$.

Answer (score 1):

We rearrange the given equation as $\frac{x-2.5}{3}=\frac{y}{2}$ so we see that the direction ratios of the line are 3,2,0 . Thus the parametric equation is $(x,y)=(a,b)+t(3,2)$ where (a,b)  is any point which satisfies $2x-3y=5$. Here it's $(4,1)$

Answer (score 1):

A parametric equation for a line is in the form $$q=p+tv,$$ where $q$ is an arbitrary point on the line, $p$ is a particular point on the line and $v$ is a direction vector for the line.

The point $(4,1)$ satisfies the equation $2x-3y=5$ and so is on the line. The point $$(4,1)+(3,2)=(7,3)$$ also satisfies the equation, and so is on the line.

Since these are two points on the line, a direction vector for the line is $$(7,3)-(4,1)=(3,2).$$  The parametric equation you have been given has therefore taken $p=(4,1)$ and $v=(3,2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $(4,1)$ is a solution (by inspection). Then

$$2x-3y-(2\cdot 4-3\cdot1)=0$$

or

$$2(x-4)-3(y-1)=0.$$

Clearly,

$$x-4=3t,y-1=2t$$ are solutions.